# Gmail doesn't display properly

Tags: google-chrome, ubuntu-mate, gmail

I am using Ubuntu Mate 16.04LTS, and so far I've been using the Firefox browser. I wanted to switch to Google Chrome, but it doesn't display Gmail properly. I tried Chromium, and it has the same problem.
I can't see right end of the screen, as if everything is streched outside of the window.

Here's what it looks like maximized and unmaximized:

[image]

[image]

I don't have this issue with other sites in the same browser.
Does anyone know what this is about, and how to fix it?
Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try zooming out, you do this by:

Menu (3 dots on chromium) -> zoom

Comment: It's not about zoom, I already tried that.

Comment: Thank you very much for your input! It made me think about zoom-options again! Problem was not in the Menu-Zoom. Problem was in an extension, called simply Zoom. As I was deleting it, it asked me why I was doing it and offerd some prepared answers , and there it was, pre-prepared answer "it was messing with my Google settings"!!! Now everything works OK! Thank you again for your time!

Comment: Absolutely no problem :)